# Floating vertical alignment and ie 7 issue

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

My floated divs worked like a charm, until I noticed a minor bug in the vertical alignment in the two top most floated divs.

The vertical alignment is off if the divs height is different does anyone know a fix for this? It wouldn't matter if the spacing was at the bottom but its at the top.

My ASCII diagram of the issue:

```
div1|annoyinggap
    |div2
    | 
____|____    
div3 div4
    |
    |
    |
____|____
```

Also in IE 7 the DIVS just show in one column rather than a nice 2 x 2 grid?

Related question: [2 x 2 div grid using float with min-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952496/2-x-2-div-grid-using-float-with-min-height)

HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="boxContainerTop">
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="Section2R2CCol"></div>  
  <div class="Section2R2CCol"></div>  
  <div class="Section2R2CCol"></div>  
  <div class="Section2R2CCol"></div> 
</div>  
</div>

.boxContainerTop {
    float: left;
}

.boxContainer {
    border: 1px solid #BBC614;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 950px;
}

.Section2R2CCol:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.Section2R2CCol {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 125px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 470px;
}
```

On a side note before someone mentions it: Yes we can argue who care's about IE 7 its history, my answer is enough of the visitors to the website use ie 7 to justify maintaining development. Any new functionality is built for ie8/ie9.

As requested: http://jsfiddle.net/yBMdc/ jsfiddle test case. css actually varies apologies for this CSS has been updated here.

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case?

Comment: i could try, not the biggest fan of jsFiddle its messed up in the past with not emulating properly. give me an hour or two just gotta finish some thigns up. thanks. :)

Comment: Try turning off "Normalized CSS". Otherwise, try [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) if you're struggling with jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yBMdc/ - hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My floated divs worked like a charm, untill I noticed a minor bug in
>   the verticle alignment in the two top most floated divs.

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.Section2R2CCol`.

> Also in ie 7 the divs just show in one column rather than a nice 2 x 2
>   grid?

Change `display: inline-block` to:

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/yBMdc/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `display: inline-block` on block elements in ie6-7. It will only work with inline elements. You should probably just float them using `float: left`.

Comment: When I do that I get the issue from the related question above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a DOCTYPE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I am using: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify,

```
.Section2R2CCol {
    display: inline-block;
    *float: left;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 125px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 470px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yBMdc/3/

Comment: Thanks for attempting but your fix hasn't actually done anything.